# Finding functions containing certain option is too slow for the first run

Tags: performance-tuning, options

I make a function like this

```
LookupOptionFunction[option_] := 
 Select[Select[Names["System`*"], StringFreeQ[#1, "$"] &], 
  KeyExistsQ[Options[ToExpression[#1]], option] &]
```

It finds functions containing a certain option. But when I start *Mathematica* and use it for the first time, it will be very very slow like

```
LookupOptionFunction[SameTest] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {58.6652,{AntihermitianMatrixQ,AntisymmetricMatrixQ,Complement,ContainsAll,ContainsAny,ContainsExactly,ContainsNone,ContainsOnly,Entropy,FindTransientRepeat,FixedPoint,FixedPointList,HermitianMatrixQ,Intersection,KeyComplement,NormalMatrixQ,OrthogonalMatrixQ,SymmetricMatrixQ,TestReport,Union,UnitaryMatrixQ,VerificationTest}}

I can't stand it cost my almost 1 minute. But when we run it second time or afterwards, it will be very speedy.

```
LookupOptionFunction[SameTest] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.520688,{AntihermitianMatrixQ,AntisymmetricMatrixQ,Complement,ContainsAll,ContainsAny,ContainsExactly,ContainsNone,ContainsOnly,Entropy,FindTransientRepeat,FixedPoint,FixedPointList,HermitianMatrixQ,Intersection,KeyComplement,NormalMatrixQ,OrthogonalMatrixQ,SymmetricMatrixQ,TestReport,Union,UnitaryMatrixQ,VerificationTest}}

It is no more than one second. What something I have meet? Or any method can do this thing?

---

I'm use it in 10.4 and 10.3.1 will be in a same situation.

Comment: I just ran your code on 10.4 (which I think you did as well) and I'm not seeing the speed-up at all. The first run was 70 seconds, the second 64. And I'm also getting "iteration limit exceeded" message (although the result seems correct).

Comment: @MartinBüttner I have update my condition.Sounds your situation is worse than me.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)"  *)
```

The iterations are using most of the time. Set a lower [\$IterationLimit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$IterationLimit.html) (lowest allowable value is 20).

```
lookupOptionFunction[option_] := Block[{$IterationLimit = 20},
      Select[Names["System`*"], 
       StringFreeQ[#1, "$"] && KeyExistsQ[Options[ToExpression[#1]], option] &]]

lookupOptionFunction[SameTest] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 20 exceeded. >>

{8.42141, {"AntihermitianMatrixQ", "AntisymmetricMatrixQ", "Complement", 
  "ContainsAll", "ContainsAny", "ContainsExactly", "ContainsNone", 
  "ContainsOnly", "Entropy", "FindTransientRepeat", "FixedPoint", 
  "FixedPointList", "HermitianMatrixQ", "Intersection", "KeyComplement", 
  "NormalMatrixQ", "OrthogonalMatrixQ", "SymmetricMatrixQ", "TestReport", 
  "Union", "UnitaryMatrixQ", "VerificationTest"}}  *)
```

The second call is faster presumably because of some caching.

```
lookupOptionFunction[SameTest] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 20 exceeded. >>

{0.548943, {"AntihermitianMatrixQ", "AntisymmetricMatrixQ", "Complement", 
  "ContainsAll", "ContainsAny", "ContainsExactly", "ContainsNone", 
  "ContainsOnly", "Entropy", "FindTransientRepeat", "FixedPoint", 
  "FixedPointList", "HermitianMatrixQ", "Intersection", "KeyComplement", 
  "NormalMatrixQ", "OrthogonalMatrixQ", "SymmetricMatrixQ", "TestReport", 
  "Union", "UnitaryMatrixQ", "VerificationTest"}}  *)
```

To identify which symbol is exceeding the iteration limit:

```
lookupOptionFunction2[option_] := Block[{$IterationLimit = 20},
      Select[Names["System`*"], 
       Check[StringFreeQ[#1, "$"] && 
      KeyExistsQ[Options[ToExpression[#1]], option], 
     Print[StringForm["`` exceeded iteration limit", #1]]] &]]

lookupOptionFunction2[SameTest] // AbsoluteTiming

(* $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 20 exceeded. >>

AllowTransliteration exceeded iteration limit

{0.559639, {"AntihermitianMatrixQ", "AntisymmetricMatrixQ", 
  "Complement", "ContainsAll", "ContainsAny", "ContainsExactly", 
  "ContainsNone", "ContainsOnly", "Entropy", "FindTransientRepeat", 
  "FixedPoint", "FixedPointList", "HermitianMatrixQ", "Intersection", 
  "KeyComplement", "NormalMatrixQ", "OrthogonalMatrixQ", 
  "SymmetricMatrixQ", "TestReport", "Union", "UnitaryMatrixQ", 
  "VerificationTest"}}  *)

Options[AllowTransliteration] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>

{77.3179, {}}  *)
```

This exceeds the iteration limit even though it has no options.

Comment: Can we found which function result the `$IterationLimit` surpass 20?

Comment: This method no longer works at least in _v12.3_.

Answer (score 3):

When we are in `13.1`:

```
CommonName[EntityValue[Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "SameTest"],"SymbolsUsingAsOption"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Select a lot faster with some clever holding of arguments:

```
optionKeysFromString[s_String] := ToExpression[s, InputForm,
  Function[sym, Keys[Options[Unevaluated[sym]], Hold], HoldFirst]
]

Select[
 Names["System`*"],
 StringFreeQ[#1, "$"] && MemberQ[optionKeysFromString[#], Hold[SameTest]] &
]
```

However, you may note that some results will be missing because some symbols only get their definition loaded when the symbol is called without a holding construct. For example, try this in a fresh kernel:

```
Options[Unevaluated @ VerificationTest]
VerificationTest
Options[Unevaluated @ VerificationTest]
```

> {}

> VerificationTest

> {MemoryConstraint -> Inherited, SameTest -> Inherited, TestID -> None,
> TimeConstraint -> Inherited}